# How do you describe calling someone a "Loser" when you mean it in a "good-natured" way

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, phrase-requests

How do you describe calling someone a *loser* in a "nice" way? What word can replace "nice"?

**There's a specific word I'm looking for but cannot dig it out of my brain.**

> "I mean loser in a   *_____* way"

It's almost the opposite of "patronising" or "condescending".

Similar words but not quite right:

> - good-natured
> - friendly
> - chummy
> - affectionate
> - sweet
> - nice
> - charming
> - lovable

**Context**:

Someone calls me this word but I have known this person for a long time and know his humour and what he is like. He says the word often and with a great big smile on his face and arm over my shoulders. I find it funny/laugh when he says it. I am trying to describe this to another person who doesn't quite get it like I feel most people here don't!

Comment: Playful? Joking? Kidding? (And calling someone a name is never nice.)

Comment: laid-back.  Calling someone a loser is never nice.  The closest is to say that he is laid-back, or takes things as they come, or thinks more of others than himself.

Comment: Thank you however they're not quite the right words. I read somewhere where it was perfectly described but have forgotten it. I agree, however, if you are in tune with the person you are talking to / have good chemistry, you can get a laugh/smile out of it.

Comment: This is neither a synonym for "nice" nor the opposite of "condescending," but I could imagine filling in the blank with *tongue-in-cheek*.

Comment: That is a good way of describing it @RaceYouAnytime so have an upvote. I believe the closest word I've come to so far is "endearing"...

Comment: Better be **very** "endearing" manner since this is a pretty nasty epithet. Why can't males be nicer to each other in the first place?

Comment: You are assuming the word is being used nastily but the word can definitely be used in a funny/joking manner as a way of affection/endearment. Context: Someone calls me this word but I have known this person for a long time and know his humour and what he is like. He says the word often and with a great big smile on his face and arm over my shoulders. I find it funny/laugh when he says it. I am trying to describe this to another person who doesn't quite get it like I feel most people here don't! Absolutely appreciate all your word suggestions nonetheless.

Comment: See also "joshing", which is like a joking form of teasing http://www.dictionary.com/browse/joshing

Comment: Why don't *affectionate* and *good-natured* work? "Affectionate insult" and "good-natured insult" are the most common terms that I know of to describe this kind of behavior among friends.

Comment: I mean this in a nice way, but you are a complete idiot if you think prefacing a sentence like this one with positive words will make it unoffensive =P (see what I mean?)

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure i can imagine taking being called a 'loser' in anything other than an offensive way. It just doesn't seem like something a *friend* would call you. If someone said "Hey buddy ya big ol loser", I'd probably still be annoyed with them and frankly a little humiliated. And I say that as an Australian (We are the kings of affectionate insult. Hell, we even turned the C word into an affectionate term somehow)

Comment: @JackNicholson I see a few comments saying they don't get it, but I'll back you up; a lot of my friends josh each other, and I completely get using a usually negative term (loser, dumbass, etc.) affectionately. It's something that only really works in person, because you need body language, and often physical contact, to get across the full point. You loser (see?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Endearing*** is the best word for the sample sentence.  (As the OP commented.)

**Sample sentence:**

> "I mean loser in an *endearing* way."

**Definition:**

> endearing (adj.)  That endears:  (a) that wins or inspires affection; 
>   (b) manifesting affection, caressing. ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/61897?rskey=xWR6jl&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid))

Not sure if that epithet can be sugar-coated though.  It strikes me the same as those who would say:

"No offense but...you are a loser."

And, of course, offense is always taken.

Might as well say:

"I'm about to punch you in the nose but you aren't allowed to tear-up, okay?"

Comment: @Jack, yes you did...updated my answer to ref. your comment.

Comment: :)  ...I know.  Thanks for checking, though.. I should have noted it anyways.  Peace.

Comment: As a native speaker, endearing does not convey what OP is asking for. Playful banter better suits what he is describing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversation#Banter

Comment: _Endearing_ would mean that you think the person is a loser, but you find that appealing about them.  It does not mean you don't honestly think the person is a loser.  I think that would be exactly condescending, for which the OP hoped to find an antonym.

Answer (score 6):

*When I call you a "loser", it's only a bit of **banter**.*

> **banter** ˈbantə/.
>   noun.
>   1. the playful and friendly exchange of teasing remarks.
>   "there was much good-natured banter".
>   —  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/banter

And a second (Irish) one is:

*When I call you a "loser", it's only a bit of **slagging**.*

> 1.1Irish mass noun
>   Good-natured teasing.
>   ‘there was a bit of slagging but it is all good craic’.
>   - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slagging

Slagging of course has another definition - "*An insulting and critical attack.*", so depends on the audience if this one works.

Answer (score 6):

One word for good-natured or light-hearted teasing is **ribbing**:

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ribbing?a=british)

> informal the act of laughing at someone in a friendly way as a joke

[YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/ribbing)

> the act or an instance of teasing or ridiculing playfully

The word originates from "rib-tickling" or "poking someone in the ribs":

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ribbing)

> "tease, fool," 1930, apparently from rib (n.); perhaps as a figurative suggestion of poking someone in the ribs. Related: Ribbed ; ribbing.

[YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/ribbing)

> ribing; meaning 'teasing', from the common practice of tickling the ribs to cause laughter.

Answer (score 4):

Positive!

> I mean loser in a ***positive*** way!

Comment: That is about as opposite of "condescending" as you can get. ;) It is, however, not what the OP is looking for (despite the wording used in their request), as "loser" can never truly be a positive label. Saying this would really only make the situation more awkward, as it amounts to a sort of sarcastic acknowledgement that you insulted them without an accompanying apology.

Comment: I don't know, there is a show called the Biggest Loser where the biggest loser is viewed positively.

Comment: There isn’t really a positive way of interpreting “loser”. It can be endearing or tongue-in-cheek … but not positive.

Comment: @Devil07 The show The Biggest Loser is about weight loss where "losing" (being a  loser) is the goal.

Comment: Although it's not easy for me to imagine the "loser" label being applied in a positive context, I wouldn't go so far as to assert it could "never" be the case. The *Biggest Loser* television show makes an interesting counterexample. @JeffC - I'm pretty sure Devil07 knows _why_ "biggest loser" is viewed positively on that show.

Comment: @J.R. Another example where "loser" is applied in a positive context, is when referring to the virtue of being a "good loser."

Comment: The reference in The Biggest Loser is a play on words. By definition a loser is one who loses but the more common usage of loser is something more like, "a person who fails frequently or is generally unsuccessful in life" (google dictionary). I don't think that definition is likely to be used a positive spin but when you consider banter or sarcasm, I think that more closely aligns with what OP is talking about.

Answer (score 4):

The way I see it, there are two primary ways to indicate that a potentially insulting statement is meant to be taken without offense:

1. Make it clear that the statement is meant to be *humorous or joking*.
2. Make it clear that the statement is *friendly.*

### Humor

- **[Tongue-in-cheek](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tongue-in-cheek)**

> characterized by insincerity, irony, or whimsical exaggeration
>
> *I mean loser in a **tongue-in-cheek** way*

- **[Facetious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facetious)**

> meant to be humorous or funny :  not serious. *a facetious remark*
>
> *I mean loser in a **facetious** way*

- **[Lighthearted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lighthearted)**

> free from care, anxiety, or seriousness
>
> *I mean loser in a **lighthearted** way*

- **[Playful](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20playful&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS752US752&oq=define%20playful&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1647j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**

> intended for one's own or others' amusement rather than seriously.
>
> *I mean loser in a **playful** way*

### Friendliness

- **[Affable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affable)**

> being pleasant and at ease in talking to others
>
> *I mean loser in an **affable** way*

- **[Good-humored](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good-humored)**

> good-natured, cheerful
>
> *I mean loser in a **good-humored** way*

- **[Gracious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gracious)**

> marked by kindness and courtesy
>
> *I mean loser in a **gracious** way*

Answer (score 1):

Benign? harmless?

But are you sure the word is loser? How can someone be a loser in a nice way?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Stick figure. It's not that one is a loser in a nice way but that you don't mean it in a horrid way. You mean it in more of an endearing way.

Comment: Perhaps affable? jovial? amicable? Good luck finding the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about *being economical with the gunpowder* as in being careful planning where to spend ones energy and time to not burn out too fast on things one probably can't affect anyway.